# NLTK stoplist удаляет не все слова

Tags: python, парсер, nlp, nltk

Возникла проблема при тематическом моделирование. Из исходного текста требуется удалить лишние слова. Для этих целей использую nltk и его корпус brown следующим образом:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
stop_words= nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('russian')
newStopWords = ['это', 'ты', 'просто']
stop_words.extend(newStopWords)
```

Все работает и добавленные мною слова удаляются из итогового мешка слов, но некоторые слова он в упор пропускает! Слово "такой" самое частое слово, которое есть в тексте и он не хочет его удалять. Это слово есть в основном корпусе, также я пробовал его добавлять отдельно, но оно все равно остается. Это не единственное проблемное слово. Из примера выше, слова "это" и "просто" отлично удалились из текста, а слово "ты" осталось.
Удаление слов и символов происходит следующим образом:

```
word=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
word_ws=[w.lower() for w in word if w.isalpha()]
word_w=[w for w in word_ws if w not in stop_words]
lem = mystem . lemmatize ((' ').join(word_w))
lema=[w for w in lem if w.isalpha() and len(w)>1]
freq=nltk.FreqDist(lema)
```

Далее идет лемматизация и дальнейшее распределение слов по частоте употребления.
В чем может быть проблема? Почему он пропускает некоторые слова, а на некоторые реагирует?
Небольшой кусочек первоначальных данных. На само содержание не смотрите, ибо это социологический проект и это одни из тысячи комментариев из разных пабликов.

```
Переменная text:
@igoralexandrovich83 а ты такой? Что твоя советь позволяет тебе гонять без правил?
И что тут такого ? Такой ор
Вытянул передний привод
@romchi_k 100%
@potapovv.a ‍♂️
```

Проблема решается удалением слов из стоп-списка уже после лемматизации. Так как в противном случае другие формы этого слова, очевидно, вылезут после лемматизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу воспроизвести описанное поведение.

Пример:

```
text = """@igoralexandrovich83 а ты такой? Что твоя советь позволяет тебе гонять без правил?
И что тут такого ? Такой ор
Вытянул передний привод
@romchi_k 100%
@potapovv.a ‍♂️"""

word=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
word_ws=[w.lower() for w in word if w.isalpha()]
word_w=[w for w in word_ws if w not in stop_words]
```

результат:

```
In [75]: word_w
Out[75]:
['твоя',
 'советь',
 'позволяет',
 'тебе',
 'гонять',
 'правил',
 'такого',
 'ор',
 'вытянул',
 'передний',
 'привод']
```

Как видно из примера, все стоп-слова были удалены.

Comment: Наверное надо было уточнить, что токенизация производится раньше. После сбора текста из файла происходит токенизация, затем исключение лишних слов и символов, а дальше лемматизация и дальше уже обработка результатов. Привел более расширенный код в первом посте. 
Я не спец в python и тематическом моделирование. Все это делается для моего учебного проекта. Уточните пожалуйста, что не так в получение word_ws? В вашем выводе Вы получили буквы перечисленные через запятую, а у меня слова в кавычках через запятую. Вот так:
_'смотрю', 'высота', 'как', 'у', 'это', 'не', 'этот', 'трек'_
Это word_ws.

Comment: @AndrewFitcher, можете привести в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример данных (`text`), который поможет воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: Добавил кусочек. Вроде выбрал специально с проблемными словами и со всякими символами. Первоначальный файл это несколько тысяч комментариев с разношерстным мусором, как в плане символов, так и в плане содержания.

Comment: @AndrewFitcher, и с вашим примером все замечательно работает

Comment: Воспроизвел Ваши действия. И правда, слова "такой" и т.д. отлично удаляются. Пробую запустить с полным текстовым файлом - снова слово "такой" самое часто употребляемое. Методом тыка я понял в чем дело. Программа оказалась неожиданно умной и за слово "такой" она воспринимает все его вариации ("такие", "такая" и т.д.). Добавив в исключение все варианты этого слова, его употребляемость сократилась с 160 слов до 4 (видимо какие-то вариации забыл). Это нормальное поведение? Мне нужно в исключения добавлять все склонения слова или есть путь проще?

Comment: @AndrewFitcher, а не проще удалять слова __после__ лемматизации? ;)

Comment: @AndrewFitcher Пожалуйста, не забывайте добавлять основное из комментариев прямо в текст вопроса. Это поможет упростить его понимание.

Comment: Вы были правы. Именно это и решает мою проблему. Из-за недостаточно глубокого понимания темы - я об этом не подумал. Удаление слов после лемматизации все решило.
Сейчас добавлю эту информацию в основной пост.